# Cpanel: want to load PHP content when clicking button

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have created a template for cpanel to business site. I want to load another PHP file when some one clicks the "Add product" button. Content want to load at gray area. It's a div. How can I do this using AJAX or JavaScript?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to change the content of the gray area

1) Wrap that gray area in a div give it id "garydiv"

2) Give all product button an id and name it "allProduct"

3) Create a php file all_product.php where you have to write your business logic

4) Use below javascript code to call you php file and get response

```
$("#allProduct").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "all_product.php", success: function(result){
        $("#garydiv").html(result);
    }});
});
```

For detail understanding of Ajax refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/